# Passing a System Exception message to another form, then using that second form to email said exception

Tags: c#, email, parameter-passing

I've been working on a custom dialog error message for my program that will give users a button to email the exception/error code to the developer. I have a separate form for the dialog error, and I've having trouble passing the exception from Form1 to the new error dialogue form I've created, then to the email button I have set up.

This is the code I'm using to forward the exception:

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Forms.Error ErrorDialog = new Forms.Error(ex.ToString());
            ErrorDialog.ShowDialog();                
        }
```

My code in the Error form's construct looks like this (I'm using a DevExpress ribbonform, in case things don't look familiar. It works just like a WinForm though):

```
public partial class Error : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    public Error(string ex)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

My problem is passing that string to my email button, which looks like this:

```
    public void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = "mailto:someone@email.com?subject=Error Code&body=" + ???;
        Process.Start(url);
    }
```

So what do I need to do to get that string attached to the email? I'm a bit of a n00b at program (as I'm sure you can tell), so maybe this is a sloppy way of trying to achieve my goal: is there a better way that's relatively simple? Does my email code need changing or overhauling (I want to use the user's default email client to compose the message)?

Comment: Do you have access to an `SMTP` server? If so directly send the email through `SMTP` instead of prompting the user.

Comment: It appears you are not saving the `string ex` that is passed to you in the constructor by assigning it to some member variable.

Comment: The days that you could fill the body of an email message with the `mailto:` protocol are long, long over.  It was abused heavily by viruses.  Use the SmtpClient class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the exception in a field:

```
public partial class Error : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    private readonly Exception _exception;

    public Error(Exception exception)
    {
        _exception = exception;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then reference this in your handler:

```
public void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = "mailto:someone@email.com?subject=Error Code&body=" + _exception.ToString();
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed; thanks! I had to edit the first form to look like this:

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Forms.Error ErrorDialog = new Forms.Error(ex);
                ErrorDialog.ShowDialog();
            }

but that was easy enough to figure out.